# Kafka topic partition zero is not getting used

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I created a topic with 3 partitions

```
Topic:fixtures  PartitionCount:3    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
    Topic: fixtures Partition: 0    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
    Topic: fixtures Partition: 1    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
    Topic: fixtures Partition: 2    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
```

I use a Java Producer to write into the topic synchronously

```
producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(KafkaProperties.TOPIC_FIXTURES, key, value)).get();
```

I have a consumer in Java which subscribes and reads from it

```
Consumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(configs);
kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(KafkaProperties.TOPIC_FIXTURES));
```

My keys are always a fixed set of 3 different strings (k1,k2,k3). But my messages are always going to either partition 1 or partition 2 -- k1 and k2 goes to partition 1 and k3 goes to partition 2.

Why is partition 0 unused?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For keyed messages, the [default partitioner](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/internals/DefaultPartitioner.java#L69) computes the partition based on a hash of the key.

With many keys, using a hash of the key is an efficient method to spread messages evenly across partitions.

But if you only have very few different keys (or if the number of keys is close to the number of partitions), it's possible it won't use all the partitions.

If that's the case, then you can provide your own partitioner to the Producer using the `partitioner.class` configuration to do round-robin for example.

Comment: Is this a documented and predictable behavior ? If possible I would like to avoid having to override anything and rely on default behavior. Thanks

Comment: Yes it is a predictable behavior as by default Kafka guarantees that messages with the same key are written to the same partition. The documentation mentions this in http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design_loadbalancing

Comment: The precise reason why Partition 0 was not getting used was that `Utils.toPositive(Utils.murmur2(keyBytes)) % numPartitions` was not returning 0 for any of the 3 keys I had. You are right in the sense that hash based distribution doesn't guarantee that all partitions will be used